# Asset Catalog Error: CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name

Tags: ios7, xcode5, asset-catalog

All of a sudden, and through no apparent changes on my end, I am now getting the following error from an image in my asset catalog:

```
2013-10-30 14:44:46.629 MyApp[38590:a0b] CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: LoginBackground scale factor: 2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 0
2013-10-30 14:44:46.638 MyApp[38590:a0b] Could not load the "LoginBackground" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.mybundleid"
```

I have tried removing the image assets and re-adding them, to no avail. The issue is happening in the simulators as well as devices. And oddly enough I can still see the image in the storyboard. Adding the images directly to the project worked as well.

Has anyone else ever seen this error? What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Update: CocoaPods 0.28.0 appears to have resolved this issue.

Are you using CocoaPods to manage your dependencies? It's possible a recent update has caused this.

I encountered the same issue with a universal app recently. Image sets that included separate, device-specific resources only included assets for a single device type after build. I similarly had made no apparent changes to the project around these assets and my storyboards appeared correct.

After Googling around, I discovered issues with Asset Catalogs reported on the main CocoaPods project (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1520) and realised that perhaps updating CocoaPods could be the change that wasn't apparent.

Rolling back my installation of CocoaPods from 0.27.1 to 0.26.2, the release before support was included for compiling xcassets in Pod dependencies, appears to have fixed this issue for now. I'll be keeping an eye on upcoming releases as it seems there is very active development in this area.

Comment: I am in fact using CocoaPods 0.27. Please update this thread if / when you learn more!

Comment: CocoaPods 0.28 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded cocoapods to 0.26.2 and it fixed the issue for me.