# CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: someimage@2x~ipad.png scale factor: 2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 568

Tags: ios, iphone, image, xcode6, iphone-6

I created app that perfectly worked on xcode 5. 
But when i run it on xcode 6 with iphone 6 simulator, it's giving me an error:

> CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: someImage@2x~ipad.png scale factor: 2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this probably isn't the answer you want, but I had the exact same problem, and simply renaming the image fixed the problem.

In other words, I copied the original file that wouldn't load to another file in the same directory, with a different name.

I then added this new file to the Xcode project and removed the first one.

I changed the code to reflect the new image name:

```
   // Asset Catalog problem loading this:
   //  [imgBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_BG@5g.png"]];
   [imgBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_BG-568h"]];
```

I slightly changed the previous developer's naming convention, to go with `Home_BG-568h@2x.png`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thnx for your rply. I got solution to my problem.

Comment: In my app, i had to use @2x~ipad images in iphone6 and iphone 6+ for some purpose. But it was not taking that images. So i just rename that images with extension other than standard type extension like "-hd". And now its working perfectly!

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this error without renaming the resources? We have hundreds of icon resources named `Icon@57x57.png`, etc. Renaming them all would be completely impractical. This all worked perfectly prior to iOS 8.

Comment: @devios, I understand your frustration, but this is Apple's problem, not mine.  It's obviously a bug in their software.  If I had a more elegant solution, I would have posted it, but sadly, I don't.  I continue to run into this problem on projects I've inherited and have no other solution.  Yes, it's time-consuming.

Comment: Hi Nate. As it turns out I found a way around it by first loading the resource into an NSData and then initializing a UIImage with that data. This loses the caching abilities of imageNamed: but for my purposes is fine.

Comment: @devios, you should post that as an alternate answer here, if you have time.  Even if the OP has accepted an answer, over time, your solution may prove useful for lots of people.  Your call, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a way to load images by circumventing Apple's naming convention interpretation. Instead of using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`, load the image as binary into an `NSData` and then initialize a `UIImage` with that data like so:

```
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Icon@57x57" ofType:@"png"]];
UIImage* icon = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Be warned, though, that there is no caching with this method and calling it multiple times will load a new image each time. If you want caching you'll have to implement that logic yourself.

The scale of the image may also not be correct. If it is a retina scale (@2x) image, you can adjust the scale of the loaded image like so:

```
icon = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:icon.CGImage scale:2.f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my universal-app-project.

The solution has also been the renaming of all "universal-images" with are used on both or only one device (iPhone && iPad || iPhone || iPad). E.G. someimage@2x.png because no counterpart exists nor is needed...