# UIButton setImage not working on custom annotation view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

As the title says, I am having trouble with the `setImage` method of the `UIButton` class.

In my code I am successfully setting up a custom annotation and custom annotation view, and I am trying to add two buttons to these callouts. I am able to add the little "i" in a circle on the right side but am getting nothing on the left side where I want a button with an image to appear.

Here is my code inside the mapView's `viewForAnnotation` method where "pin" is my custom annotation view which was set up with mapView's `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` method and casted to my custom view after which it is tested to see if it is nil.

I believe the path to the image is correct as when it is different than what is written I was able to get error messages concerning the existence of the image. another thing is that when I click either the info button or anywhere on the callout, the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method is called, how do I fix the method being called anywhere on the callout and how could I differentiate between the two buttons within the method.

```
    if(!pin){
        pin = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        UIButton *buttonInfo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [buttonInfo addTarget:nil action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         UIButton *buttonCar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [buttonCar addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/car.png"];
        if (image) {
            [buttonCar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/car.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"Your image is nil");

        }
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = buttonInfo;
        pin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = buttonCar;
    }
```

Comment: You should probably "refactor" your explanation to make it more readable. It will help people to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not setting the frame of your button which means it is basically invisible.

Try something like this:

```
    UIButton *buttonCar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                        [buttonCar addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/car.png"];
    if (image) {
            [buttonCar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/car.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {
              NSLog(@"Your image is nil");                      
    }

    buttonCar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

**EDIT**: if this doesn't work and your logging is indeed saying your image is nil, try these steps to solve your issue:

- Make sure your image is indeed included in the target that you are building by selecting the file in the Project Navigator and opening the File Inspector pane on the right. Is there a checkmark next to your target? (assuming you are not using an asset catalog)
- Check the spelling of your image - upper/lowercase will be an issue if you are testing on a device (Simulator is more forgiving). Also, you shouldn't require the full path to the image if it is part of your bundle. i.e. just use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"]`

Comment: I tried this, both before and after setting the image, but it still doesn't show up. Also, something to mention is that image registers as nil so I get the NSLog to print out that its nil, though taking out the if statements and just  setting the image and frame, nothing shows up.

Comment: Ok. This exact code works for me with the only change being the path to the image. Have you tried just setting the background colour of the button to see if the button is indeed there and the issue lies with the path to your image? Clearly this seems to be the case as your image is shown as being nil.

e.g. `buttonCar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Comment: Changing the background color appears to have done nothing for me. I have a folder by the name of "Images.xcassets" that I was trying to access the image from. My knowledge seems to be a bit messed up. does bundle refer to the folder that all of your .h and .m files and other assets needed?  I was able to get the image to show up by going to file and then to add files to my project, going through images.xcassets and through the car imageset and adding the image.png in there that was of the car, but that leaves the image in the file navigator listed with all my coding files. but if I had tons?

Comment: Ok, so you are using an asset catalog (with the files being automatically collected in the Images.xcassets folder). Did you check that the asset catalog is included in your target (again by selecting your Images.xcassets file in the Project Navigator and making sure your target is checked in the File Inspector pane on the right). Assuming your image set in the catalog is called "car", you can access it programmatically like this (without the file ending):
`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car"];`
An image set is created automatically when you drag an image into the asset catalog.

Comment: This might be helpful for understanding asset catalogs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingImageSets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH3-SW1
http://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-Image-Assets

Comment: My project's name is checked under the Target Membership section on the file inspector, and when I try to use just the name of the image, car, I get output saying "CUiCatalog: can't find rendition for name: car scale factor: 2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 569." That might be something I did though...

Comment: Check out this question, which might help you resolve your error message:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375863/asset-catalog-not-being-used-in-project

Comment: Nope, the image is already set to universal, and I don't use CocoaPods